# To Show that $(\Bbb R,d)$ is bounded and complete but not totally bounded.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

On the set $\Bbb R$ of reals consider the metric $d$, given by $d(x,y) = min \{ 1, |x-y| \}$. To Show that $(\Bbb R,d)$ is bounded and complete but not totally bounded.

Bounded can be easily verified and completeness comes from the euclidean metric and since they are equivalent.

To prove that $d$ is not totally bounded because if we take $\epsilon =\frac 12 $ no finite number of open balls can cover the whole $\Bbb R$.

I am having a confusion with the totally bounded part. Is the logic of the proof correct?

Comment: yes it is right. Balls with radius 1/2 are the same in the usual metric and in the one you consider.